# Field extension associated to morphism of a curve X to $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, IV Ex. 2.2:

Fix an algebraically closed field  $k$ of char $\neq 2$.

(a)If X is a curve of genus $2$ over $k$, the canonical linear system $|K|$ determines a finite morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree 2. Show that it is ramified at exactly 6 points, with ramification index 2 at each one.

(b)Conversely, given six distinct elements $\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{6} \in k$, let $K$ be the extension of $k(x)$ determined by the equation $z^2=(x-\alpha_{1})...(x-\alpha_{6})$. Let $f:X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the corresponding morphism of curves. Show that $g(X)=2$.

I know how to do part(a), but for part(b) I am confused how does the field extension associated to this morphism, and how do we know its ramification points from this equation $z^2=(x-\alpha_{1})...(x-\alpha_{6})$?

Comment: have you read chapter I.6 especially corollary 6.12? to get the function field, mod out k(x)[z] by this equation, and project the curve onto the x axis, via (x,z)-->x.  can you see the branch points?  you need to look also at infinity, where you can use Prop. 6.8 and the fact there are an even number of branch points.